# How to change rsyslog configuration file directory

Tags: rsyslog

Does anyone know how I can recompile rsyslog for Ubuntu 10.04 so that /etc/rsyslog.conf is read from another location, say for instance /tmp/rsyslog.conf?

Answer (score 3):

By default, rsyslogd reads the file /etc/rsyslog.conf. This may be changed by command line option "-f".